# Openstack Train via Kolla-Ansible net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables Networking Issues

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, iptables, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I've installed Openstack Train via kolla-ansible (requires docker since the services are in containers) on 3 nodes.  All 3 nodes are compute nodes and the one doubles as a controller/networking node.  The 2 compute nodes run only the Openvswitch agent. Docker requires the kernel setting net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=1 (sysctl.conf) to function correctly.  However, on the compute-only nodes, this breaks TCP/IP IPv4 communication with VMs on these nodes.  ARP works without issue. While I have not tested IPv6, this also appears to work.

For example, creating a new instance on a compute-only node using an Ubuntu Focal cloud image leaves the Ethernet port, typically ens3, unconfigured for IPV4.  ICMPv4 pings also fail on VMs on the compute-only node to for example, a Neutron router interface.  Setting net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0 resolves these issues but breaks docker and Openstack functionality, at least for services running on a Magnum cluster.  I did not notice this issue on Openstack Rocky (upgrade to Stein and then immediately to Train) especially on the creation of a new VM.

As a work around I added iptables rules for the compute-only nodes per the following:

```
brctl show |grep 8000 |cut -f 1 |xargs -I % sudo sh -c 'if [ '%' != 'docker0' ]; then iptables -A FORWARD -i % -o % -j ACCEPT; fi;'
```

While this appears to resolve the issues, there may be unintended consequences that I'm unaware of.  It will also require subsequent executions, or at least a script/service that runs via cron or systemd that adds new bridges, when a new bridge is added via the creation of a new VM, etc.  Can anyone comment on if the above iptables rules will create other issues and if there is a better solution to this problem, e.g., via an Openstack configuration setting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On Openstack, Train release using Kolla-ansible (runs docker containers of the services), with the host's kernel setting net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=1, the VM can be arpinged but not pinged or connected to (networking is broken).  Setting net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0 resolves this issue but breaks docker iptables forwarding and thus also breaks networking (at least when set on the controller).  There is a further description of the problem @https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?312824-Bridge-broken-after-docker-install.

Is there a solution that resolves this?